# SQL Server: select query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got 3 tables: **projects**, **employee** and **project_employee**

**employee**

- ID (int, PK)
- Name

**projects**

- project_id (int, PK)
- project_name

**project_employee**

- project_id  (int, PK)
- employee_id  (int, PK)

What I trying to do is write a query that get ID and Name of all employees that are not in a project, for example project number 9.

So I tried:

```
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM [employee], [project_employee] 
WHERE [employee].ID != [project_employee].emp_id AND [project_employee].project_id = 9;
```

but I always get empty result, something must be wrong with my logic?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[employee].ID = [project_employee].emp_id AND [project_employee].project_id != 9` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name 
FROM [User] u
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM [project_employee] pe
                   WHERE pe.project_id = 9 
                     AND pe.employee_id = u.ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead try something like this, it should get you all users that are not part of `project_id = 9`

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name 
FROM [User] u
WHERE u.ID NOT IN (SELECT pe.employee_id
                  FROM [project_employee] pe
                  WHERE pe.project_id = 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to get the required data

```
select e.id,e.name
from employee e
left join project_employee pe
on e.id = pe.employee_id
left join projects p
on pe.project_id = p.project_id
where p.project_id is null
```

(OR) Just left join with `project_employee` table. No condition has been checked assuming that all employees with no project at hand is the desired output.

```
select e.id,e.name
from employee e
left join project_employee pe
on e.id = pe.employee_id
where pe.project_id is null
```

Comment: Table `projects` is not required in order to get the result. Also this will only return employees who are in a project with no name, because the `project_employee` table can have only non null entries because all the fields are in the primary key and because probably there is a foreign key on `project_id`. I.e. for every project in `project_employee` there is a record in `projects`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, that's the hole query which will work even if OP wants to fetch project_name. I didn't checked for the condition `project_id = 9` cause that was not the intention probably as OP mentioned in post saying that `an example` (probably he wants to get all employee with no project).

Comment: Because of the inner join the query will only return employees with projects, so the query is wrong anyway.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, that's a hurry mistake. thanks for pointing.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, edited the answer to be per with the posted question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN project_employee pe
    ON pe.employee_id = e.id
      AND pe.project_id = 9
WHERE pe.employee_id IS NULL
```

You don't even need projects table since you are not looking for employees on a project.

Comment: The OP wants employees who are not in a **specific** project. For example project number 9, he says.

Comment: ok, added a specific one, still don't have to use all 3 tables.

Answer (score 1):

He asked for the ability to check that the employees are not in a specific project.  The **not in** solution is fine, but I generally prefer using left joins.

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN project_employee pe
  ON pe.emp_id = e.id
  and pe.project_id = 9
WHERE pe.employee_id IS NULL
```